# VSCode: Assign key command to a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In previous editors I've users, notably SublimeText and Atom, I was able to create a simple command to add a character like `&nbsp;` when I type `option-space`.

In Atom, for example, I created the command in `init.coffee`:

```
atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
 'editor:insert-nbsp': (event) ->
   editor = @getModel()
   editor.insertText('&nbsp;')
```

and then the easy part, a keybinding to call the custom command:

```
  'alt-enter': 'editor:insert-br'
```

In vscode, I know how to do the latter (create a keybinding) but how to create the command.

I realize I can create a snippet, which I have made several of, but I want to essentially trigger the `&nbsp;` snippet with a keybinding.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had trouble with this, so here's the whole process of creating a keybinding, snippet, and linking them together:

### 1. Create a Snippet

1. File > Preferences > User Snippets > New Global Snippets file...

   *This will prompt you to create a snippets file.*
2. Name the new Snippet file whatever, I'll name mine "global"

   *This will create a file called `global.code-snippets`*
3. Create your snippet

   *The new snippet file will have an example commented out. Just uncomment that to follow along.*
4. Save The file

   *You now have a global file with a single snippet. Typically snippet files will have many snippets, and are divided according to workspace, environment or something else - this is outside of this scope, but you'll get the hang of it once you start creating more advanced snippets.*

### 2. Create a Key Binding

1. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

   *This will open your Keyboard Shortcuts menu*
2. In the upper-right corner of the editor window, find the button that looks like brackets => `{}` => click it

   *This will open `keybindings.json`, a file where you can store your custom keyboard shortcuts.*
3. In the bottom of the editor pane, you will see a button that says "**Define Keybinding (Ctrl+K Ctrl+K)**" Click that

   *This will prompt you to enter a key combination.*
4. Push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   *Ctrl+Shift+c is recorded, and Enter creates a new keybinding for that key combination automatically.*

### 3. Link the Keybinding to the Snippet

In case you don't need the deeper explanation, here's what your new key binding should look like at the end:

```
[
    {
        "key":"ctrl+shift+c",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "name": "Print to console"
        }
    }
]
```

1. In the keybinding, change the command to "editor.action.insertSnippet"

   `"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",`
2. Add an args key, it's value is an object

   *When you start typing `args` VSCode will pick up on it and suggest a code completion, go ahead and press tab or enter, and it will automatically put quotes and build an empty object for you.

   `"args": {}`
3. Inside the `args` object, add `name`.

   *Same things as before, just type name, VSC will suggest a code completion, accept it, and it will build out the necessary syntax.

   `"args": { "name": "" }`
4. The `name` refers to the snippet name, which is the first element of the snippet object. For our example, this will be "Print to console".

   `"args": { "name": "Print to console" }`

### 4. Make sure it works

1. Create or open a javascript file (any file that ends with `.js`)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>
3. `console.log('')` sould be printed in your file
4. If it doesn't work make sure the names match exactly - capitalization matters!

Answer (score 5):

It's actually much easier in VSCode since 1.9:

```
{
 "key": "alt+space",
 "command": "type",
 "args": {
   "text": "&nbsp;"
 },
 "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `Keybinding` and assign a `Snippet` to it.

To to that you must use `editor.action.insertSnippet` as `command`, and your snippet name in `args` attribute.

Follow this example:

```

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+i",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "name": "YourSnippetName" // name of a snippet defined by an extension or user
    }
}
```

```